# Redmine Issue creation not working via receive_IMAP Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, imap, redmine, gmail-imap

I am currently trying to create issues in Redmine using email. The e-mails are read but no issue is created in redmine application.

**My environment :**
Redmine version : 2.3.0
Ruby version : 1.9.3
MySQL version : 5.5
Using bitnami redmine stack

**Here is my rake command.**

```
rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" \
  host=imap.gmail.com ssl=1 port=993 \
  username=****@gmail.com password=**** \
  move_on_success=success move_on_failure=failed \
  unknown_user=accept project=mail \
  allow_override=tracker,project,priority
```

**Here is my mail content for issue creation**

> This is a new issue that overrides a few attributes [...]
>
> Project: mail Tracker: Bug Priority: Normal Status: New Subject: Issue

I'm pretty sure the rake command works fine. Because once i execute the rake command, the mail in ***inbox*** folder is moved to ***failed*** folder. I have tried several email patterns but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue sorted out myself after a week of research. Added the below two attributes to the rake command. But I've been sending mail from the mail of project members only. Not sure though what I've been missing.

move_on_failure=failed
unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1

Pls find the updated rake command.

```
rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" \
  host=smtp.gmail.com ssl=1 port=993 \
  username=*****@gmail.com password=**** \
  folder=Inbox \
  move_on_success=success move_on_failure=failed \
  unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1
```

Comment: `host=smtp.gmail.com` is a mistake? Not imap?